# "Жив" - прилагательное / наречие / глагол?

Tags: семантика

... *до тех пор пока **жив** человек*.

Слово **жив** - это краткое прилагательное/наречие от **живой** или какая-то особая короткая форма от глагола **жить**?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *... до тех пор пока **жив** человек.*
>
> Слово **жив** - это краткое прилагательное/наречие от **живой** или
> какая-то особая короткая форма от глагола **жить**?

***Жив***  — краткая форма прилагательного ***живой.***

.

Перед [***пока***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_175) стоит поставить запятую:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не только. Еще и деепричастие.

Comment: _Не только. Еще и деепричастие._ === Конечно. Но речь-то шла о конкретном предложении...

Comment: А вот в конкретном предложении сильно смахивает как раз на причастие или отглагольное прилагательное.

Comment: _А вот в конкретном предложении сильно смахивает..._ === Смахивает. Потому что обозначает качественное состояние, протекающее во времени. И тем не менее  — не причастие.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Slava!!!

Answer (score 0):

Жив - это деепричастие от "жить". Но в этой роли редко употребляется, в современном языке практически исчезло, хотя форма "живши" еще иногда используется.

Омонимичное "жив" - кратная форма от прилагательного "живой". Но может выступать и в роли краткого причастия (и отглагольного прилагательного) от "жить". В сочетании с "был жив" / "будет жив" по грамматической функции логично трактовать именно как причастие.

Аналогично, антоним "мёртв" является краткой формой прилагательного, но по выполняемым функциям  сближается с причастием.

Это ситуация объясняется тем, что "живой" и "мертвый" в некоторых значениях (далеко не во всех) одновременно могут характеризовать и качество и состояние определяемого слова.

Вообще вопрос оказался интересным. Я сгоряча было отмахнулся, но потом понял, что исследовательская проблема тут есть.

Answer (score 0):

Извините за возврат к этому старому вопросу, сегодня случайно вышла на него. Дело в том что, некое слово, похожее на прилагательное/наречие, определяется по следующему простому принципу: если слово в предложении ОБСЛУЖИВАЕТ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ (субъект или объект), то оно является прилагательным (полным или кратким), или же причастием, которое в предложении выполняет или  атрибутивную функцию, или же - функцию сложного сказуемого. Если же это слово ОБСЛУЖИВАЕТ ГЛАГОЛ (то есть уточняет действие, выраженное глаголом-сказуемым), то мы имеем дело с наречием. В данном примере ЖИВ это краткое прилагательное, так как оно очевидно относится к какому-нибудь субъекту -"кто-то жив". Вопрос: Кто-то каков? В каком состоянии? Обычно при постоянных качествах-описаниях субъекта/объекта употребляется полная форма прилагательного, а при временных качествах, которые уже переходят из постоянного признака в краткое состояние,- уместна краткая форма прилагательного(сравните: " У НЕЁ РЕБЁНОК БОЛЬНОЙ"(субъект понимается, как неизлечимо, или трудноизлечимо больной, то есть здесь долгосрочное качество) и "У НЕЁ РЕБЁНОК БОЛЕН" (здесь говориться уже о временном состоянии, и поэтому излечимом. Другое дело, что многие, не понимая такую тонкость русского языка, коверкают его и приучают наше ухо к этому.

Если же мы хотим убедить всех, что слово "ЖИВ" это наречие, то его срочно надо поставить в предложении в такую позицию, чтобы оно описывало/уточняло действие, выраженное глаголом, и тогда оно должно будет отвечать на вопрос "Как?" делалось это действие. В таком случае в функции наречия данное слово обязано будет принять другой внешний вид и оставаться неизменным, а именно: делать что-либо КАК? -живо. Живо - это наречие.